# convert curl command to golang function

Tags: go

I'am new in golang developing, i want to upload file to dropbox using golang, this is my curl command :

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload --header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/file_upload.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}" --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @build.bat
```

this is my actual function :

```
func uploadFile(filename string, token string){

    jsonData := make(map[string]string)
    jsonData["path"] = "/file_upload.txt"
    jsonData["mode"] = "add"
    jsonData["autorename"] = true
    jsonData["mute"] = false

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", nil)
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
    req.Header.Set("Dropbox-Api-Arg", "{\"path\": \"/file_upload.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

problem is i dont know how add --data-binary @build.bat in my go code, and how use my variable jsonData in Dropbox-Api-Arg set.

Comment: Check out https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/ (no affiliation, just something I've found useful before)

Comment: @Adrian yes, but this not convert me the complet curl command

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: --data-binary @build.bat

Comment: It's the same as `--data`. Go doesn't make a distinction between handling of binary and ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--data-binary @build.bat` says "Use the contents of the file named build.bat as the request body". Since any io.Reader works as an HTTP body in Go, and *os.File implements io.Reader that's easy enough:

```
f, err := os.Open("build.bat")
defer f.Close()
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", f)
```

The Dropbox-Api-Arg header is already there. Presumably its content isn't static, so just replace it with the JSON encoding of your map:

```
jsonData := make(map[string]string)
jsonData["path"] = "/file_upload.txt"
jsonData["mode"] = "add"
jsonData["autorename"] = true
jsonData["mute"] = false

b, err := json.Marshal(jsonData)
req.Header.Set("Dropbox-Api-Arg", string(b))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Peter